# How to batch-resize PNG files?

Tags: image, image-processing

I have a number of PNG image files that I'd like to increase in size. **I do *not* want to rescale the image.** I just want to extend the white background further down and to the right. In GIMP terms what I want is to increase the Canvas Size, and cover the increased area with white pixels, in a batch context. The input images may be different sizes, but the output images should all be a fixed size (e.g.: 1280 x 720 pixels).

I've tried this with various online tools, with GIMP, and with a very old version of Photoshop. Most of the tools I've tried to date do one of the following which I *don't* want:

- Rescale the existing image to cover the new canvas size, or
- Center the starting image and extend the canvas in all directions, or
- Fail to perform this in a batch mode.

I just want to extend existing PNG images with additional white pixels down and to the right. What's the easiest way to do this to a large number of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ImageMagick command that did what I needed used "convert" with the -geometry and -composite arguments. In a Windows batch file context:

```
for %%a in (img*.png) do (
   magick convert -size 1280x720 xc:white "%%a" -geometry 512x384+40+40 -composite "work-%%~na.pdf"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

imagemagick is a common tool for this. the `-crop` operation combined with `-gravity` can probably do what you want.

`magick input.jpg -crop 1000x1000+0+0\! -background white -flatten output.png`

source for the magick spell: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/

[image: input]
[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

In ImageMagick, you process a whole folder of images using mogrify. You can extend them using -extent. With mogrify, it is wise to first create a new empty directory to hold the results. So

```
cd image_directory
mogrify -format png -path path/to/new_directory -background white -gravity northwest -extent WxH *.png
```

Where WxH, is your desired final width and height after padding with the white. This assumes that all images will be padded to the same width and height

**Expand By Size**

```
cd test1
mogrify -format png -path ../test2 -background white -gravity northwest -extent 500x500 *.jpg
```

**Expand By Percent**

```
cd test1
mogrify -format png -path ../test2 -background white -gravity northwest -extent 150x150% *.jpg
```

For ImageMagick 7, add magick before mogrify. So "magick mogrify ..."